# Did Burning out damage my trucks rear end gears

Tags: rear-end

I've had My Dodge 1500 Crew Cab for a year and the rear end just crap the bed while my son was driving it, apparently right after he did massive burn out. I believe the damaged is directly caused from my son repeatedly doing burn outs with the traction control off, which he apparently has been doing all the time according to his sibling and friends, which obviously I was unaware of.  So am I wrong in my "diagnostic assumption"?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! We probably can't say for sure, but it definitely didn't do the rear end any favors. When doing burnouts, it heats the gears/grease in the rearend, which can cause premature failure. If it's low on fluid, the situation is only exacerbated.